# Cron not working, No Heartbeat task found Check if cron is configured correctly

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, schedule

non of my scheduled talks are working, no emails are being sent.

in System> Scheduler I get an error message

No heartbeat task found. Check if cron is configured correctly
[image]

AS far as I can tell Cron is set up correctly and I'm a loss as to how to fix it
[image]
what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you've correctly configured cron in admin, but you have to configure cron 
 on server end too for this to work.

Check out detailed explanation for this in magento official docs [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_install.html?_ga=2.217736021.2105500426.1535677975-533450319.1535335241#install-cron)

Check "Setting Up Cronjobs" section of the page to be more specific.

Comment: it's asking me to add these  `* * * * * ! test -e /home/new2magento/public_html/maintenance.flag && /bin/bash /home/new2magento/public_html/scheduler_cron.sh --mode always
* * * * * ! test -e /home/new2magento/public_html/maintenance.flag && /bin/bash /home/new2magento/public_html/scheduler_cron.sh --mode default` which I have done but I jst receve error emails